# What is the difference betwen these boost asio async functions?

Tags: boost-asio

I am new in boost and I want to use async function but I can understand what the difference is  between

```
socket_.async_send and  asio::async_write?
```

and similarly these two

```
socket_.async_recive and  asio::async_read?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is when the completion handlers for completion will be called.

In the case of the `socket` member functions, the completion handler will be called "when the send operation completes", even if not all of the data has been actually transmitted to the peer.

In the case of the free functions, the completion handler will be called when all the supplied buffers have been written.

See:  [This documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html)